# All c# project was unloaded

Tags: c#

I encountered this error

[image]

after cloned my project.

i tried to reload the project but it didn't work.

how to resolve this?

Comment: did you check `output -> General` tab, You will find errors which causing unloading of your projects

Comment: yeah, there's no errors occur

Comment: Did you try restart the visual Studio?

Comment: yeah, didn't work also

Comment: i solved the problem, by matching my current sdk version in global.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem, by matching my current sdk version in global.json

this are my procedure,

[image]

[image]

Result

[image]